# Workflows Dissapearing SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have been working on an workflow that automatically sends a HTML formatted email to a specific user group. However, sometimes when I open my site and look for the workflow in Sharepoint designer, **its gone :O.**
Ill go back to it later and itll be exactly where it should be. Anyone have any idea why this is happening. This is extremley frustrating and any help on this issue would be very much appreciated.

What Ive done so far:

- Restarted computer
- Restart Sharepoint designer 2010
- look everywhere I know for the workflow

Comment: I know I had a problem where with some sites, when I'd click into the workflow section of Designer and my workflows would be gone. I'd click away and back into that section and they'd be there. More annoying than anything, if this is what's happening to you, too.

Comment: Having exactly that problem except when I click away and come back its still gone :(. Ive been trying to see what works and refreshing the workflow tab (right-click on workflow tab) seems to work about 50% of the time. I wonder if this is something else that is causing this, or if it is a bug in the program.